# Prove $|AD|^2=|AB|\cdot |AC|-|DB|\cdot |DC|$ in triangle $ABC$, D the point where bisector of angle $A$ intersects $\overline {BC}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In a triangle $\triangle ABC$, the bisector of angle from the point $A$ intersects $\overline {BC}$ in point $D$. Prove: $|AD|^2=|AB|\cdot |AC|-|DB|\cdot |DC|$.

I don't even know where to start. I'll probably have to use the power of a point on a circle theorem but I don't know  how.

Comment: You can get there using [Stewart's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem) and the [Angle Bisector Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Steward's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem) to get:

$$AB^2\cdot DC + AC^2 \cdot DB = BC(DC \cdot DB + AD^2)$$

$$AD^2 = \frac{AB^2\cdot DC + AC^2 \cdot DB}{BC} - DC \cdot DB$$

So we need to prove that: $\frac{AB^2\cdot DC + AC^2 \cdot DB}{BC} = AB \cdot AC$. For this we can use the [Angle Bisector Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem). So:

$$AB^2 \cdot DC + AC^2 \cdot DB = AB \cdot \frac{AC}{DC} \cdot DB \cdot DC + AC \cdot \frac{AB}{BD} \cdot DC \cdot BD$$
$$ = AC \cdot AB (DC + BD) = AC \cdot AB \cdot BC$$

Thus:

$$\frac{AB^2\cdot DC + AC^2 \cdot DB}{BC} = \frac{AC \cdot AB \cdot BC}{BC} = AC \cdot AB$$

Hence the proof.