# Non-trigonometric proof: $|AD|^2=|AB|\cdot |AC|-|DB|\cdot |DC|$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, solution-verification, triangles

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2907905/721644) has already been asked before, but the answer gives the solution involving trigonometry and Stewart's theorem which I wanted to avoid.

> In a triangle $\triangle ABC$, the bisector of angle from the point $A$ intersects $\overline {BC}$ in point $D$. Prove: $|AD|^2=|AB|\cdot |AC|-|DB|\cdot |DC|$.

---

**My approach:**

Let $c$ be the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ and let $E$ be the intersection of the line $AD$ and circle $c$.

We obtain the following:

$\begin{aligned}\measuredangle ABC=\measuredangle AEC\ \land\ \measuredangle EAB=\measuredangle CAE&\implies\boxed{\triangle ABD\sim\triangle AEC}\\&\implies\frac{|AC|}{|AE|}=\frac{|AD|}{|AB|}\\&\implies|AB|\cdot|AC|=|AD|\cdot(|AD|+|DE|)=|AD|^2+|AD|\cdot|DE|\\&\implies\boxed{ |AD|^2=|AB|\cdot|AC|-|AD|\cdot|DE|}\end{aligned}$

On the other hand:

$\begin{aligned}\measuredangle CBE=\measuredangle CAE\ \land\ \measuredangle EDB=\measuredangle ADC&\implies\boxed{\triangle DBE\sim\triangle ADC}\\&\implies\frac{|BD|}{|AD|}=\frac{|DE|}{|DC|}\\&\implies\boxed{|BD|\cdot|DC|=|AD|\cdot|DE|}\end{aligned}$

Finally,

$|AD|^2=|AB|\cdot|AC|-|AD|\cdot|DE|=|AB|\cdot|AC|-|BD|\cdot|DC|$

**Picture:**
[image]

---

May I ask if this is valid? If so, is there anything I could do to improve my proof?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The proof seems valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the second step ($|BD|\cdot|DC|=|AD|\cdot|DE|$ is a well-known theorem ([Intersecting Chords Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_chords_theorem)), so you might just as well refer to it instead of proving it yourself. Other than that, this proof is perfectly valid, and being very short, I can't see how it could be improved.